# Смена файла css через javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно реализовать при нажатии на ссылку или любой другой элемент css файл менялся на другой или просто смену фона и цвета текста если так проще, я не знаю javascripta, все что нашел в интернете у меня не работало. Что-то типо переключателя между дневным и ночным режимами. Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Простейший вариант (*Если разговор идёт про смену режимов*):

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

btn[0].onclick = function() {
  document.body.className = 'day';
}

btn[1].onclick = function() {
  document.body.className = 'night';
}
```

```css
* {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.day {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.night {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>день</button>
<button>ночь</button>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('change-mode');
}
```

```css
* {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.change-mode {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">сменить режим</button>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

Comment: @DawdM  в каком браузере не работает ?

Comment: @DawdM я щас с мозилки смотрю - работает

Comment: css копировали ?

Comment: @DawdM, всё должно работать, ищите ошибку=)

Comment: @DawdM я тоже скопировал и всё работает в Firefox Window 10 PRO https://jsfiddle.net/97oqyvga/2/

Comment: @DawdM  вставьте в body этот script и заработает и отметьте решением - Артур   зря писал что ли ??код рабочий

Comment: @Arthur галочку поставить ?

Comment: jquery не при чём ...Артур написал на чистом js

Comment: Есть такой ещё вопрос можно это в одну кнопку сделать ?

Comment: @Arthur да все работает, только не могу понять как сделать что бы в header-e тоже менялся цвет, меняется только фон body

Comment: @DawdM, задайте ещё один вопрос, покажите код, который не работает, сделайте наглядный пример, так больше шансов, что вам помогут

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли )

Comment: @DawdM, всегда пожалуйста=)